# Leaflet Markercluster do not cluster if geoJSON is MultiPoint

Tags: javascript, leaflet, markerclusterer

I am facing one issue on leaflet markercluster plugin.
Marker Cluster plugin works perfectly if the GeoJson type is "Point".
But it fails to cluster if the GeoJson type is "MultiPoint".
I found a post [here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/425), where it says that it doesn't recursively look into child layers.
I am stuck with this.
Please suggest if there is any work around.
Thanks